Matplotlib not displaying all the values from Pandas Dataframe
I have already looked in many places for a cure to this problem, but found nothing which applies to my situation.
I have a Pandas Dataframe displaying 3 months of rolling 6day total Rainfall compared to the Valentia Observatory 30 year averages from 1961-1990 and 1991-2020
The graph plotted is not displaying all the data, it is missing the last few days of data. The plot finished in March, but the data finishes in April.
I have tried this for a 1 year plot too, same problem, in fact that one misses the last 5 months of data!
I have tried my code with and without the DateFormatting for the x axis, no difference.
Here is the start and end of my Dataframe:
    TMSTAMP      diff_1961_1990    diff_1991_2020
0   2024-01-13     -100.000000     -100.000000
1   2024-01-14      -98.157863      -98.358824
2   2024-01-15      -24.472389      -32.711765
3   2024-01-16       11.756303       -0.435294
4   2024-01-17       22.809124        9.411765
..         ...             ...             ...
81  2024-04-03      218.307087      123.754613
82  2024-04-04      175.433071       93.616236
83  2024-04-05      170.236220       89.963100
84  2024-04-06      103.976378       43.385609
85  2024-04-07       93.582677       36.079336

Here is my code:
def plot_yearly_6day_rolling_averages_diff_valentia(self):
    title = 'Plot 3 Month 6 Day Rolling Rainfall Average c/w Valentia Averages'
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(800 / 96, 400 / 96), dpi=96)
    ax_rainfall = fig.add_subplot()
    plt.tight_layout()
    ax_rainfall.set_title(title, fontproperties=self.font_prop, fontweight='bold', size=10, color=self.colour_title)
    filename = '{}{}'.format(self.upload_folder, self.rainfall_6hrly_diff_valentia)
    x = self.df_rainfall_diff.index    
    y_1961_1990 = self.df_rainfall_diff['diff_1961_1990']
    y_1991_2020 = self.df_rainfall_diff['diff_1991_2020']
    ax_rainfall.set_ylabel('Rainfall Difference %', fontproperties=self.font_prop, size=8, color='fuchsia')
    major_fmt = md.DateFormatter('%m-%d')
    ax_rainfall.xaxis.set_major_formatter(major_fmt)
    plt.setp(ax_rainfall.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), ha="center", rotation=45)
    ax_rainfall.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(7))
    ax_rainfall.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(20))
    ax_rainfall.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(10))
    ax_rainfall.legend(loc="best")
    ax_rainfall.bar(x, y_1961_1990, width=0.05, color='fuchsia', label='Rainfall Difference 1961-1990 Valentia')
    ax_rainfall.bar(x + 0.2, y_1991_2020, width=0.05, color='blueviolet', label='Rainfall Difference 1991-2020 Valentia')
    plt.grid(which='both', linestyle='dotted', linewidth=0.3)
    plt.savefig(filename, format="png", transparent=True, dpi=96)

Is it something subtle in the bar line width or something to do with the tight layout?
I have tried adding bbox_inches='tight' to the plt.savefig, but still same problem.
Also the Legend is not showing up correctly, it is just a small box top right with no content.
Here is the graph:

Help much appreciated.

A quick remark: plt.tight_layout() doesn't have an effect if you call it at the start of the code. It usually is the last command before calling plt.show() or plt.savefig(). Also, ax.legend() should be called after all the calls to functions such as ax.bar(..., label=...).

Many thanks, @JohanC, for the very helpful remark. The Legend is now showing up. I have moved the plt.tight_layout() to the end, but the last few plots are still missing.

If a bar has no pixels it will not show up. Set your dpi to 300 or so or save as a pdf.
Also suggest layout=‘constrained’ rather than tight_layout

@JohanC I originally thought there was data missing, but the problem is that the x axis labelling is not correct. I have just re-run my plot using no x-axis labelling and I have the correct number of plots. However when I add x-axis date formatting the date labelling is incorrect. The first label is 01-01 when it should be 01-19 so all the other labels are incorrect

To rotate x ticks, the correct way is ax_rainfall.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45). Also, you should first do the plotting (i.e. ax_rainfall.bar(...) before changing the formatting and the ticks. You can call ax_rainfall.bar(...) just after fig.add_subplot(). When you haven't drawn the bars yet, matplotlib can't know which tick labels there should be.

@JohanC, thank you for being so patient!
OK, I have moved all my formatting to after the plot.
The x-axis Labels are now correctly angled, but start a 01-01 still instead of 01-19.
I have to use x = self.df_rainfall_diff.index for the x axis because of moving the bars slightly to the right when doing the secoind plot.
I do not understand why the x-axis labels are not starting at the first item in  the DataFrame

Here is my current x-axis formatting:
ax_rainfall.set_xticklabels(self.df_rainfall_diff['TMSTAMP'])         ax_rainfall.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(7))         major_fmt = md.DateFormatter('%m-%d')         ax_rainfall.xaxis.set_major_formatter(major_fmt)         ax_rainfall.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)

I finally decided to fix this by creating a list of x-label positions and x-label text in the format '%m-%d' and then changed the formatting for the x-ticks to this:
ax_rainfall.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(7))    ax_rainfall.set_xticks(x_ticks)    ax_rainfall.set_xticklabels(x_labels, rotation=45)
This did the trick, so the correct labels are now showing.
